# version control and deployment with eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, version-control

I am working an a php webapp with eclipse as my IDE.  I would now like to set up a version control system to manage my source code.  I would also like to use the plugin to deploy my code live to the server.  Can anybody recommend a plugin (subclipse?) and perhaps explain how I would use it to deploy my code?

Answer (score 3):

To setup a version control you can try Subclipse

"To deploy your code to the server" I guess you meant FTPing files .. you can try SFTP http://www.jcraft.com/eclipse-sftp/

To install Subclipse --

1. Open Eclipse.
2. Choose Help → Software Updates...
3. Select the Available Software tab, and press the Add Site... button.
4. In the Add Site dialog box, for the Location, enter:

   ```
   http://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/csse/binaries/Eclipse/Subclipse
   ```

   Type carefully (or copy from this web page and paste into Eclipse). Case matters. No spaces.
5. Back in the Available Software tab, you will now see some new options. Check the following two checkboxes:

   ```
   JavaHL Adapter (recommended)
   Subclipse (required)
   ```

   The subboxes of the above two checkboxes will get checked automatically.
6. Click Install...
7. Click Next, then click the button to accept the license agreement.
8. It will install automatically (see the progress bar in the lower-right portion of the Eclipse window; wait for it to complete). Then you will need to restart Eclipse.

[To how to use Subclipse read more](http://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/csse/resources/Subclipse/installation.htm)

To install SFTP --

You need Eclipse SDK 3.3(or higher) to enjoy this software.

1. Help > Software Updates > Find and Install...
2. Choose Search for new features to install
3. Click New Remote Site..., and then put http://eclipse.jcraft.com/ for the URL field.
4. Choose SFTP Plug-in, and then click Select Required button.

For Eclipse SDK 3.2, try the Update Site http://eclipse.jcraft.com/3.2/

Tips

```
* The location 'sftp://192.168.0.1/tmp' will allow you to get accesses to 'tmp' directory under user's home directory. On the other hand, 'sftp://192.168.0.1//tmp' will point to '/tmp' directory on the remote.
```

[Read more regarding SFTP](http://www.jcraft.com/eclipse-sftp/)